# Install SSH Key Task fails in post-job phase

Tags: azure-devops

I've been using Azure DevOps for a while now and just recently started seeing this error on the `Install SSH Key` task during the post-job phase. I'm running this task on a Windows `Hosted Agent` (MS provided) to enable the git checkout to succeed pulling the source via ssh from the SCM system.

The error I started getting just recently suggests it's trying to do some Linux things during post-job to clean things up disregarding it's actually running on a Windows host:

```
##[error]Error: kill ESRCH
```

I wonder if other people have been experiencing this and if there are workarounds available while a fix is worked on.

Comment: Do you have this issue before? Can you enable system.debug to True and share the detailed log? Can you close the browser and open a new one?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT didn’t have it before just started a few days ago and by looking at the GitHub repo where the tasks are coded it looks like it was identified and fixed and it’s being released in version 0.156.1

Comment: Let's wait for the new release and kindly let us know whether your issue solved with new release.